# Azure Maps Basic JS Initialization Throws Error with JQuery

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-maps

I'm trying to use Azure Maps with their JS Web SDK. I'm following the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-map-control up to the point of just adding in my subscription key and it's throwing an error.

I've tried removing all the options, and it prompted for credentials, so I know I'm authenticated. When put in an identifier that isn't in the DOM, I get an error saying it can't find the id. When I put in the correct ID, I get a white draggable background with the Microsoft logo on the bottom. Because, from the debugger, it seems the call came from `this.map.setStyle(this.styleBuilder.build()),` I tried giving extra style options and I tried removing center, zoom, and language. I also tried using `window.onload`. All in all, the issue persists.

All that is required is to load the scripts and to insert this snippet:

```
var map = new atlas.Map(<div id>, {
    center: [-122.33, 47.6],
    zoom: 12,
    language: 'en-US',
    authOptions: {
        authType: 'subscriptionKey',
        subscriptionKey: '<Your Azure Maps Key>'
    }
});
```

which I did.

Just that snippet generated this error:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of 
    undefined
    at Object.at [as getReferrer] (atlas.min.js:3066)
    at new r (atlas.min.js:3066)
    at n._updateStyle (atlas.min.js:3066)
    at n.setStyle (atlas.min.js:3066)
    at e._rebuildStyle (atlas.min.js:3391)
    at atlas.min.js:3391
at  @   atlas.min.js:3066
r   @   atlas.min.js:3066
n._updateStyle  @   atlas.min.js:3066
n.setStyle  @   atlas.min.js:3066
e._rebuildStyle @   atlas.min.js:3391
(anonymous) @   atlas.min.js:3391
Promise.then (async)        
e._setStyleComponents   @   atlas.min.js:3391
(anonymous) @   atlas.min.js:3391
Promise.then (async)        
e   @   atlas.min.js:3391
(anonymous) @   myScript.js:787
```

And this is the error message with pretty print:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
    at Object.at [as getReferrer] (atlas.min.js:formatted:25499)
    at new r (atlas.min.js:formatted:47165)
    at n._updateStyle (atlas.min.js:formatted:52481)
    at n.setStyle (atlas.min.js:formatted:52475)
    at e._rebuildStyle (atlas.min.js:formatted:60131)
    at atlas.min.js:formatted:60219
at  @   atlas.min.js:formatted:25499
r   @   atlas.min.js:formatted:47165
n._updateStyle  @   atlas.min.js:formatted:52481
n.setStyle  @   atlas.min.js:formatted:52475
e._rebuildStyle @   atlas.min.js:formatted:60131
(anonymous) @   atlas.min.js:formatted:60219
Promise.then (async)        
e._setStyleComponents   @   atlas.min.js:formatted:60172
(anonymous) @   atlas.min.js:formatted:59678
Promise.then (async)        
e   @   atlas.min.js:formatted:59673
(anonymous) @   myScript.js:formatted:787
```

EDIT:
I started going though and commenting out my scripts in the header. When I removed all JQuery script tags the map worked. (I then verivied I was working on the lastest version of JQuery). But now of course my page doesn't work.
Also while it was working I checked out what the `origin` property was that threw the error. The code was `self.location.origin` with `self` being `window`. So now I have an incompatibility.

If anyone can provide some assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't come up with a reason as to why it's not working. But I did manage to get my page to load correctly.

Basically, since Azure Maps was trying to reference a `self` that was supposed to point to `window` but was `null`, what I did was declare `self` before initializing `map.

```
var self = this;
var map = new atlas.Map(<div id>, {...
```

It's a hack, it's ugly, but it works.